# Limit checkboxes that can be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am creating dynamic list on page. And the input element is propagated with data from db.

What I want to do is list the data, in input elements, with a checkbox at the end of each line. But I only want to be able to allow a user to click any 3 of the checkboxes.

Could be 20 options, but only 3 can be selected.

From here they can then proceed. So I have a submit button that I wish to disable unless 3 are clicked.

So the input elements and checkboxes are like so.

```
<input class="inputLONG" type="text" READONLY value="123 Hauton Road, Burpengary QLD 4506" class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="approved" id="check1" value="1" type="checkBox" />
<input class="inputLONG" type="text" READONLY value="86 Clandestine Boulevard, Beachmere QLD 4505" class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="approved" id="check2" value="1" type="checkBox" />
<input class="inputLONG" type="text" READONLY value="82 Sentinnel Court, Raby Bay QLD 4178" class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="approved" id="check3" value="1" type="checkBox" />
<input class="inputLONG" type="text" READONLY value="1 Lido Court, Wellington Point QLD 4200" class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="approved" id="check4" value="1" type="checkBox" />
```

And the Order Button. Which needs to be disabled unless three checkboxes are ticked.

```
<span class="samplePromo">Order</span>
```

Any help appreciated.

Oh and NO LESS than or NO MORE than 3 can be selected.

Comment: Been looking for this. +1 Favorited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a small snippet to do this for you in jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mvelaga/Ed8jQ/

**Edit:**

New fiddle to address the scenario discussed in comments

http://jsfiddle.net/mvelaga/kKGcJ/1/

Comment: Is there a reason that none of the checkboxes are clickable?

Comment: @Matt: some of the changes to my fiddle got reverted, I don't know why, I have created a new fiddle, please have a look now. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. As we are using CSS to display the submit button, it has a hover effect. Would be cool, to change opacity of the css button , until all three checkboxes are clicked. Voted best answer thanks

Comment: Here's a version of this in pure JS (to see how it works under the hood): http://jsfiddle.net/mkmcdonald/N3MVb/7/

Comment: Issue I have is @Mahesh Velaga, how would I have two of these running on the same page, but working separately ? Matt I couldnt see the difference of yours, but works the same as other code. What was difference. Really would like to attach an alert to the submit button, if user tries to click it, stating you need to select 3 items

Comment: @422: Just refine the selections to your checkboxes (probably pass this as a param to the method that I specified in the fiddle), so we can apply our function on narrower checkbox collection. Would this solve the problem that you are talking about? Did I get your question correctly?

Comment: No. You didnt Mahesh.
Basically I have two areas on one webpage, where I want to run this, but I want them separate, and not to conflict. I have one div with the fiddle you made, where user must select 3 checkboxes. And another area on same webpage where user must select 2 checkboxes. However the checkboxes are for different data streams, so are NOT connected with each other.
So if you took your code and added it to ONE webpage, and make it work so each doesnt affect other.. issue seems to be the id checkbox, which I am not sure how to get around.

Comment: @422: It seems I did get your question, since the solution that I suggested actually solves the problem that you just described. I updated my answer with a new fiddle (implementing my suggestion) to address this. Let me know, if this is what you want. Thanks.

Comment: Why disable checkboxes after 3 have been selected? If I changed my mind I can't select the new one and then de-select another one. It forces me to do the de-selection first for no obvious gain.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: This is one way of doing what OP wants. I felt, since we are enforcing 3 selections, if all 3 are filled up, you *need* to make a deselection to not violate the rule, hence disabling, which forces that.

Comment: @Mahesh: disabling checkboxes does **not** prevent violating the rules, as I can still deselect one and still violate the rule. It just forces me to violate the rule in a different way.

Comment: @Joachim: I think, as per OP's requirement from the question, I thought before 3 checkboxes are selected, the submit needs to be disabled and we shouldn't allow the user to select more than 3 checkboxes. Which is what I am trying to do. Could you suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: @Mahesh: of course you can disable the submit button, but I see no reason for disabling the other checkboxes. Personally I'd disable the submit button and show a message saying "Please select exactly 3 items".

Comment: @Joachim: What would happen when there are 3 checkboxes selected and I need to change the selection to some other checkbox, in your case?

Comment: @Mahesh: As a user? I'd have the choice of *either* selecting the new one and deselecting a previous one **or** do it the other way around.

Comment: @Joachim: "The other way around" is what I am doing in my case. If we allow the user to select a new one (there will be 4 selected checkboxes now) and then deselect a old one, we will violating the rule - `But I only want to be able to allow a user to click any 3 of the checkboxes`.

Comment: @Mahesh: and the other way around you'll be violating the rule "NO LESS than [..] 3 can be selected". At this point it's nitpicking, because you **will** be violating some rule, but it doesn't matter **as long as the user can't submit** in that state.

Comment: @Joachim: I forgot about this line `Oh and NO LESS than or NO MORE than 3 can be selected.`, just looked back at the question after your above comment. In that case, you approach is as valid as mine. But, as I said, mine is just one way to do what the OP asked, except for "No less than 3 checkboxes" being selected.

Comment: @Joachim: And after clearing up of all this confusion, to answer your original comment, I guess I went with my present approach to get rid of alerts when user clicks more than 3 checkboxes and partly because the other approach doesn't actually limit the number of checkboxes to be selected (and it seems that my present approach is what OP actually wants).

Comment: @Mahesh thanks for your code, it does EXACTLY what we want, not sure on others issues. But EXACTLY what we want, thank you very much.

Comment: We have sorted the disabled button also, which now means we do not require an alert just made samplePromo[disabled] css

Answer (score 3):

Found a script to do I think.

http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-limit.php

Answer (score 2):

write custom function which will fire onclick (or onchange) of checkbox, disable rest of them when 3 are checked, enable buttom, react opposite if less than 3 are on...

Comment: Yeah I get the theory ! :) lol, but need to know if anyone can whip up a fiddle or some example script